# calling variables into different functions within the same class in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a password generator and checker program in python. At the moment I have finished the gui but I am having trouble making the tkinter label update and display the textvariable as it just comes up with a blank space instead of 'error', 'weak' etc. someone else helped me with the generator but what they did wouldn't work in this case unfortunately.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Check your password", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        entry = tk.Entry(self, bd =6)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", command=checkPassword(entry.get()))
        self.update
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Strength:", font=controller.title_font)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=passwordStrength, font=controller.title_font)
        entry.pack()
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        label2.pack()
        label3.pack()

    def checkPassword(password):
        passwordStrength = tk.StringVar()
        strength = ['Password can not be Blank', 'Very Weak', 'Weak', 'Medium', 'Strong', 'Very Strong', 'Password must be less than 24 characters']
        score = 1
        print (password), len(password)

        if len(password) == 0:
            passwordStrength.set(strength[0])
            return

        if len(password) > 24:
            passwordStrength.set(strength[6])
            return

        if len(password) < 4:
            passwordStrength.set(strength[1])
            return

        if len(password) >= 8:
            score += 1

        if re.search("[0-9]", password):
            score += 1

        if re.search("[a-z]", password) and re.search("[A-Z]", password):
            score += 1

        if re.search(".", password):
            score += 1

        passwordStrength.set(strength[score])
```

If you require more info on what my project is, or the rest of the code, just ask. All help is much appreciated, thanks in advance:)

Comment: It's great that you reduced your code, but a [mcve] needs to be complete: we need to be able to run the code so we can tinker with it.

Comment: should I just put all the code back in then?

Comment: Briefly, the `passwordStrength` name in `checkPassword` is local to that method, it's not visible in the `__init__` method.  BTW, `checkPassword` is missing a `self` arg, so its `password` arg is actually equivalent to `self`.

Comment: It would be best if you can reduce it down to a small runnable program that illustrates your current problem. If you can't figure out how to do that it's ok to post the whole thing, since it's only 150 lines or so. OTOH, in the process of making the MCVE you may figure out how to fix it yourself. ;)

Comment: I defined passwordStrength at the top though, and made it a global variable, but how do I fix it?

Comment: We can't see any globals in what you posted. And really, it's best to avoid globals: they make it much harder to analyze the code. One of the big reasons to use classes is so you can do stuff without using globals.

Comment: and now it's throwing p this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//4006fs01/intake13$/213152/Documents/Jack Walker NEA/might work.py", line 165, in <module>
    app = SampleApp()
  File "//4006fs01/intake13$/213152/Documents/Jack Walker NEA/might work.py", line 54, in __init__
    frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
  File "//4006fs01/intake13$/213152/Documents/Jack Walker NEA/might work.py", line 99, in __init__
    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Enter", command=checkPassword(entry.get()))
NameError: name 'checkPassword' is not defined
>>>

Comment: @j.walker You should rather update your question to its current version and include the error message as well.

Comment: As Nae said, you need to put that error message into the question itself, where it belongs.  Put it in a code block, to preserve the formatting. And we really need to see a MCVE, it's pointless posting an error message without posting the code that caused it.

Comment: I suspect that you need to improve your understanding of how names work in Python. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. And you should probably also take a look at this tutorial: [A Beginner's Guide to Python's Namespaces, Scope Resolution, and the LEGB Rule](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "*calling variables into different functions within the same class in tkinter*" is to simply have those variables assigned to class attributes.

As a tkinter example with such behavior, below code produces a label, and after 1 second calls a function that changes the label's text looking up to a class attribute:

```
import tkinter as tk

class VariableAssignedAsAttribute(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        aVariable = "some string"

        self.anAttribute = aVariable

        self['text'] = "Unchanged Text"

    def updateLabel(self):
        self.config(text=self.anAttribute)




root = tk.Tk()

lbl = VariableAssignedAsAttribute(root)
lbl.pack()

root.after(1000, lbl.updateLabel)

root.mainloop()
```

I'd check the references that [PM 2Ring](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4014959/pm-2ring) provided in the comments.